# Can't catch all the events using ethers

Tags: node.js, events, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

Can't catch all the events. Why?

I try to listen to events for several contracts and it is ok. But the more contracts I listen to, the more events are missed? Is there any way to prevent this and why event listening does not work correctly when I want to listen to, for example, 100 contracts at once. Are there any guidelines how to do it correctly ?

Such a trivial question. Maybe I should just listen to one contract for each file, only it seems a bit punitive....

My code looks like most tutorials and so it starts like this:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contract,  abi , provider )
    //  contract.on("Transfer", async (from, to, value, event, error) => {  
      ///test
```

I tried both ethers js and web3. In both cases, when I listen to more events in one file, more often the event is not recorded, and I want to make sure that it captures 100% of the events